# Qemu doesn't boot kernel after “Uncompressing Linux… done, booting the kernel. ”

Tags: linux, kernel, android, arm, qemu

I've compiled qemu for s5pc110 (it's from http://gitorious.org/samsung-linux-platform/qemu, somebody had added support for s5pc110), version 0.12. But when I load the kernel:

```
qemu-system-arm -M s5pc110 \
 -kernel ../../kernel/android-samsung-2.6.35-gingerbread/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
 -initrd arm_root.img -serial stdio -append earlyprintk
```

the terminal prints "Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel." and nothing. The vlc windows also have nothing. When I debug with gdb, I find it doesn't execute `start_kernel`.
What's the problem? Is qemu for s5pc110 wrong or kernel?

And I could't set breakpoints at head.S, decompress_kernel also couldn't.
Why?

BTW, if I use `-nographic`, I could't interrupt the shell but kill the terminal, the `CTRL+a x` doesn't help.

Also I want to know how to let whole kernel start log print in the current terminal with qemu? Which option of qemu can do this?
Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?